# I would like to update the table but the error code 'PLS-00103' occurs every time I try this

Tags: stored-procedures, plsql, oracle11g

```
DECLARE 
    Emp_Number NUMBER(5);
    Salary NUMBER(5);
    Salary_increment NUMBER(5);
BEGIN
     SELECT Employee_Salary 
     INTO Salary 
     FROM EMPLOY_TABLE;
END;
BEGIN
     SELECT Employee_ID 
     INTO Emp_Number 
     FROM EMPLOY_TABLE;
END;
BEGIN
    IF Salary <= 20000 THEN
       Salary_increment := (Salary/100) * 12.5;
    ELSIF Salary > 20000 AND employee_Salary <= 40000 THEN
       Salary_increment := (Salary/100) * 11.5;
    ELSE
        Salary_increment := (Salary/100) * 10;
    END IF;

    UPDATE EMPLOY_TABLE 
    SET Employee_Salary = Salary + Salary_increment  
    WHERE Employee_ID = Emp_Number;
END;
```

Comment: Typo alert: it's **salary** - not "salery" ....

Comment: but i know that't not causing the error **marc_s**

Answer (score 1):

You have too many BEGINs and ENDs.  Variables are only scoped to the block they are declaredy in (and any nested blocks within that).  So variable `salary` is not accessible in the 3rd block, for example.  Try:

```
DECLARE 
    Emp_Number NUMBER(5);
    Salary NUMBER(5);
    Salary_increment NUMBER(5);
BEGIN
     SELECT Employee_Salary 
     INTO Salary 
     FROM EMPLOY_TABLE;

     SELECT Employee_ID 
     INTO Emp_Number 
     FROM EMPLOY_TABLE;

    IF Salary <= 20000 THEN
       Salary_increment := (Salary/100) * 12.5;
    ELSIF Salary > 20000 AND employee_Salary <= 40000 THEN
       Salary_increment := (Salary/100) * 11.5;
    ELSE
        Salary_increment := (Salary/100) * 10;
    END IF;

    UPDATE EMPLOY_TABLE 
    SET Employee_Salary = Salary + Salary_increment  
    WHERE Employee_ID = Emp_Number;
END;
```

If you needed nested block, for example for exception handling, you could do this:

```
DECLARE 
    Emp_Number NUMBER(5);
    Salary NUMBER(5);
    Salary_increment NUMBER(5);
BEGIN
     BEGIN
       SELECT Employee_Salary 
       INTO Salary 
       FROM EMPLOY_TABLE;
     END;
     BEGIN
       SELECT Employee_ID 
       INTO Emp_Number 
       FROM EMPLOY_TABLE;
     END;
     BEGIN
       IF Salary <= 20000 THEN
           Salary_increment := (Salary/100) * 12.5;
       ELSIF Salary > 20000 AND employee_Salary <= 40000 THEN
           Salary_increment := (Salary/100) * 11.5;
       ELSE
           Salary_increment := (Salary/100) * 10;
       END IF;

       UPDATE EMPLOY_TABLE 
       SET Employee_Salary = Salary + Salary_increment  
       WHERE Employee_ID = Emp_Number;
    END;
END;
```

But this is superfluous here.